# Returning a nested structure from a function

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, structure

I am writing code in which I want to return a nested structure. I wonder how to do that.

```c
    static int ORDERID = 0;
    struct item
    {
        struct data
        {
            int orderid;
            char content[10][20]; 
        } details;
        struct node *next;
    };
    typedef struct item product;
```

So insertion of a new product contains two parts:

1. details structure
2. pointer pointing to next product

In the `details` structure I have to have different types of product description, say:

1. Shoes with its orderid, and other details in the array of strings (`char content[10][10]`)
2. Shirt with its orderid, and other details in the array of strings (`char content[10][10]`)

So for the insertion of a new product I need a function to return a `details structure` i.e the nested structure of the product.

How to do that?

Comment: You can use `struct data` as the return type of a function.

Comment: I guess `struct node *next;` should be `struct item *next;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `struct data` as the return type of a function

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can actually define the `struct data` outside of the `struct item` and then use `struct data` to define a variable `details` inside of `struct item`. That is,

```
struct data {
    int orderid;
    char content[10][20];
};

struct item {
    struct data details;
    struct item *next;
}
```

And, then you can freely return a `struct data` object from a function.

EDIT :

If you want to create a function which can return a `struct data` object you can probably do the following :-

```
struct data * function_data() {
    struct data *someData;
    someData->orderid = 16;
    someData->content[0] = "Shoes";
    return someData;
}
```

I hope this adds further quality to the answer.

Comment: Even without this we can directly return struct data

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I guess, it wouldn't be accessible outside of its scope if you declare it inside the other struct. \_(```)_/

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I have edited the answer to my best understanding, best of luck :)

Comment: No..though it is inside a structure you can access it ..